# Let $ L \supseteq K $ be a finite, separable extension and $ N $ its normal closure.

Tags: galois-theory

Prove that there is only a finite number of intermediate fields in the extension $ N \supseteq K$. I know that if $ N = K(\alpha)$ , ie, $N$ is simple, then the result holds. So I want to prove that's the case. Any help? Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is an immediate consequence of the fundamental theorem of Galois theory. Do you know it?

Comment: Is it? Sorry, but maybe I'm a little bit tired. Can you clarify me how?

Comment: @Crostul's hint is that $N/K$ is separable and normal, hence Galois.

Comment: Yeah, that's true. Also, if I'm not wrong, $N/L$ is Galois but I can't  get it yet. I mean, who is this alpha?

Comment: Ok, I got it :) tahnks